# Load title and its links for given menu?

Tags: php, joomla

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788975/1052402) which outputs all the menus and their attributes. How can I get all the titles and their links for one specific menu (I have three)?

Comment: I believe it's all over the documentation.

Comment: I've checked this page amongst others as well (http://docs.joomla.org/JMenu/1.6). Unless I'm missing something, could you tell me where then?

Comment: If its so obvious do please let me know as I still can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get default menu - JMenu object
$name='blah'; //Name of your menu alias here
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu($name);

// Get menu items - array with menu items
$items = $menu->getMenu();

// Look through the menu structure, once you understand it
// do a loop and find the link that you need.
var_dump($items);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above code but it gives the same output as the question I linked to in my initial post. I have made sure the menu alias/type is correct but the output is still given for all menus.

Comment: OK try passing the $name into both instances of getMenu(); So like `$items = $menu->getMenu($name);`

Comment: Gives the same results unfortunately.