# Joomla Get menu id from names

Tags: joomla, menu, parameters

I am in joomla 2.5 and I try to get the id of a menu, I have the name, the alias

exemple :

menu = FAQ-> menu item =FAQ

I have try :

```
$app         = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$params      = $app->getParams();
$idfaq       = $params->get('content_id_faq');
```

but i am a newbie so I dont even know if content_id_faq is correct

thanks

Comment: We need to know more about your menu structure to help you. Have a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3788975/309163 for more information on how to get the correct item.

Comment: Thanks, It's not like I want in the first place but it will work so I will use the method 2

Comment: Glad that I could help - I have added that as an answer so please mark that one as accepted / upvote if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788975/309163) for more information on how to get the correct item.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that either the menu item alias or the article alias  must be unique within either the `#__menu` or `#__content` table, they just need to be unique within that menu-parent item branch or the category, respectively.  Since you are making something custom for a specific site you could modify the queries in the other answer to reflect this; I would do that rather than assuming no one in the future is ever going to use the same aliases. Of course you could write a plugin to basically make those aliases reserved words.  Also in your code I would force that to cache so you aren't constantly doing that query.